# Android menu item with icon

Tags: android, menu

Can you please tell me how can I create an android menu item with icon.
Im insert image from menu main.xml but not working

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_cut"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="cut"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_copy"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="copy"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_past"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="past"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `showAsAction` as **`ifRoom|withText`**

```
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/img"
    android:title="title"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Icons are used for toolbar buttons. You have `android:showAsAction="never"`, forcing this item into the overflow. The overflow does not use icons.

Answer (score 0):

programmatically set the icon like this:

```
     menu.add(0, MENU_QUIT, 0, "Quit").setIcon(R.drawable.menu_quit_icon);
```

or You can set it in your xml layout like this:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/save_button"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
          android:title="Save Image"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported in Android 3.0+ http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Help this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) will help you to understand menu